# How do I disable native .net code debugging in visual studio?

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Recently I got curious and enabled "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" in Visual Studio. After enabling, I had to wait a bit while the source code was downloaded (or at least I believe that's what it was doing). The next time I debugged some code, the debugger broke because it couldn't find the source file for Lazy.cs. I tried to locate the file and couldn't find it (and I forgot where the source files were downloaded to). Eventually I decided to just disable the setting and go about my business. I unchecked the option in settings.

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have solved the problem. Any time I hit F11 to step in to some code that uses lazy loading, it tries to open Lazy.cs and throws an error "Lazy.cs not found". I have the option to browse for the file, but I don't know where it is or even really want to deal with it. I just want to disable the setting. Am I missing something? Is this a known bug? Is it a different setting than the one im looking at?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing to do with native code debugging.  You changed more than one setting to enable source stepping.  Put the [green circles back](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have figured out the answer. When I selected native code debugging, it automatically selected a directory to look for symbols in. The directory is C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache (found by going to Properties - Debugging - Symbols). Even after I disabled native code debugging, for some reason it was still looking in that directory for symbols. I simply cleared that textbox option and the problem was solved.

Comment: Amazingly, this was the only thing that worked for me too. Disabling the option(s) didn't do it, nor did clicking "Clear symbol cache" or other seemingly reasonable things. The local symbol cache path in the text box must truly be cleared!